# how to make use of radiogroup and checkbox in an single activity?

Tags: android, android-layout

how to make use of radiogroup.setonCheckedchangelistener and checkbox.setonCheckedchangelistener in a single activity?
i am facing a problem while?
please any one help me....Thanks in advance

Comment: What problem are you having? How are you trying to make use of these? How can we help you w/o knowing these things?

Comment: i am making use of setoncheckedchangelistenerfor radiogroup and checkbox it is not accepting..please tell me any way?

Comment: Post your code for more help

Comment: ok thanks my doubt is cleared

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you need no implement two diffrent `CheckedChangeListener` for radio group and checkbox.

`OnCheckedChangeListener` is for radio group and `android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener` is for checkbox.

you need to implement two different `CheckedChangeListener`

refer below code for both radio group and checkbox.

```
public class abcd extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener,android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{

    RadioGroup rd;
    CheckBox cx;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.abcd);

        rd  =  (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        cx = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        
        rd.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        cx.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        

    }
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

        // Here you can get your Radio button checked id
        System.out.println("radiogroup checked");
        
    }
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        System.out.println("checkbox checked");
        
    }

}
```