# How to get CheckBox value present in RadioGoup in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, checkbox

New to Android,
I am creating a question Answer App. So I want to get the value of checkBoxes.
I know how to get value of radio button present in Radio Group.
But I want to know is it good practice to keep checkBixes in RadioGroup and how to get the Checkboxes value?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by getting `CheckBox` value? You can get the state (checked or not checked) and you can also get the text label for the `CheckBox` itself (`getText()`).

As for keeping them in a `RadioGroup`, it will depend largely on your use case (when grouped, the user might expect that only one `CheckBox` at the time can be checked). If you were to implement `RadioGroup`, you will have to implement a listener and then determine which `CheckBox` was checked. For that you can look at the accepted answer [on this closely related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520036/how-to-make-use-of-radiogroup-and-checkbox-in-an-single-activity).

Here is how you can get the Text of the `CheckBox` that was checked/unchecked:

```
@Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(checkedId); 
       //here you can check if it was checked or not, including the text
       String text = checkBox.getText().toString();
       boolean isChecked = checkBox.isChecked();
    }
```

I hope this sheds some light.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately as you would expect to utilize radioGroup's *getCheckedRadioButtonId()* for radio buttons, there is no such thing for check boxes. There are many ways to do this but I think the simplest and cleanest way would be the following:

**For CheckBoxes**

```
// Define one listener to use it for all of your CheckBoxes:
CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener listener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
       // You can also use the buttonView.isChecked() instead of isChecked parameter too : if(ButtonView.isChecked)..
       if(isChecked) {
           // Do stuff with this checkBox for example:
           String stringToShow = buttonView.getText();
         }
      }
    };
// Reference your CheckBoxes to your xml layout:
CheckBox checkBox1 = findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
CheckBox checkBox2 = findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
// and many more check boxes..
        
/* Set the above listener to your Check boxes so they would
notify your above piece of code in case their checked status 
changed:*/
checkBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);
checkBox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);
// and many more check boxes..
```